# Find Duplicate case and close

Tags: apex, trigger, case

I shall appreciate ur help.
Can anyone help me on this Requirement :
Requirement is :

1) Create a case with Subject line  (User ) ----First Case

2) Create another case with Same Subject line [either by (Same user or different user )] .----Second Case

3)Now System should automatically identify it as a " Duplicate case and close the case " (i.e second case)  .

4)Now the Case Comments of the Closed case (i.e second case) should be added to the existing case ( i.e first case) which is open.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert) {
        Set<String> caseSubs = new Set<String>();
        Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Case> listCases = new List<Case>();
        List<CaseComment> listCaseComm = new List<CaseComment>();
        List<CaseComment> listInsertCaseComm = new List<CaseComment>();
        Map<String, Id> mapCasSubId = new Map<String, Id>();
       Map<Id, CaseComment> mapCaseIdCasComm = new Map<Id, CaseComment>();

        for(Case cas : trigger.new) {
            caseSubs.add(cas.Subject);
            caseIds.add(cas.Id);
        }

        listCases = [SELECT Id, Subject, Description FROM Case WHERE Subject IN : caseSubs AND Status = 'Closed'];


        if(listCases.size() > 0) {
            for(Case cas : listCases) {
                mapCasSubId.put(cas.Subject, cas.Id);
                caseIds.add(cas.Id);
            } 

           listCaseComm = [SELECT Id, CommentBody, ParentId FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId IN : caseIds];       

            for(CaseComment casComm : listCaseComm) {
                mapCaseIdCasComm.put(casComm.ParentId, casComm);
            }                  

            for(Case cas : trigger.new) {
                if(mapCasSubId.containsKey(cas.Subject)) {
                   cas.Status = 'Closed';
                  listInsertCaseComm.add(new CaseComment(ParentId = cas.Id, CommentBody = mapCaseIdCasComm.get(mapCasSubId.get(cas.Subject)).CommentBody));
              }
           }

           if(listInsertCaseComm.size() > 0) {
                insert listInsertCaseComm;
           }
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This was a tricky one.

I've built a complex map, containing the Cases & related CaseComments for each Subject contained in `trigger.New`.

I've then taken the earliest open Case per subject & left that open, whilst closing all other Cases with that subject & moving their related CaseComments to the original Case.

I've commented the code, so have a read through & give it a try, and let me know how it goes.

```
    trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {

    Map<String, Map<Id, Map<Case, Map<Id, CaseComment>>>> subjectCaseCommentsMap = new Map<String, Map<Id, Map<Case, Map<Id, CaseComment>>>>();
    Map<String, Id> subjectOpenCaseId = new Map<String, Id>();
    Map<Id, Case> casesToUpdate = new Map<Id, Case>();
    List<CaseComment> commentsToInsert = new List<CaseComment>();

    // Gather the subjects
    for (Case c : trigger.New) {

        if (!subjectCaseCommentsMap.containsKey(c.Subject)) {

            subjectCaseCommentsMap.put(c.Subject, new Map<Id, Map<Case, Map<Id, CaseComment>>>());
        }
    }

    // Gather all Cases with those subjects & their related CaseComments
    for (Case c : [ SELECT
                        Id,
                        Subject,
                        Description,
                        (
                            SELECT
                                Id,
                                CommentBody,
                                ParentId
                            FROM
                                CaseComments
                        )
                    FROM
                        Case
                    WHERE
                        Subject IN :subjectCaseCommentsMap.keySet()
                    AND
                        IsClosed = FALSE
                    ORDER BY
                        CreatedDate ASC ]) {

        // Add this Case to the map
        if (!subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(c.Subject).keySet().contains(c.Id)) {

            subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(c.Subject).put(c.Id, new Map<Case, Map<Id, CaseComment>>());
        }

        subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(c.Subject).get(c.Id).put(c, new Map<Id, CaseComment>());

        // Take note of the first Case for each subject
        if (subjectOpenCaseId.get(c.Subject) == null) {

            subjectOpenCaseId.put(c.Subject, c.Id);
        }
        system.debug('Line 52: Found a Case ' + c.Subject + '. Related comments: ' + c.CaseComments);
        // Add related CaseComments to the map
        if (!c.CaseComments.isEmpty()) {

            for (CaseComment com : c.CaseComments) {

                subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(c.Subject).get(c.Id).get(c).put(com.Id, com);
            }
        }
    }

    // Now see if any of those Cases need to be closed
    for (String sub : subjectCaseCommentsMap.keySet()) {

        // Only proceed if there are duplicates of this subject
        if (subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(sub).size() > 1) {

            for (Id cId : subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(sub).keySet()) {

                for (Case c : subjectCaseCommentsMap.get(sub).get(cId).keySet()) {

                    // Is this Case the first Case for this subject?
                    if (subjectOpenCaseId.get(sub) == c.Id) {

                        // Do nothing, this is the first Case for this subject

                    } else {

                        // Close this Case, and clone the CaseComments
                        c.Status = 'Closed';

                        casesToUpdate.put(c.Id, c);
                        system.debug('Line 84: Closing Case ' + c.Subject + '. Related comments: ' + c.CaseComments);
                        for (CaseComment com : c.CaseComments) {

                            commentsToInsert.add(
                                new CaseComment(
                                    CommentBody = com.CommentBody,
                                    ParentId = subjectOpenCaseId.get(sub)
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('Line 99: casesToUpdate: ' + casesToUpdate);
    system.debug('Line 100: commentsToInsert: ' + commentsToInsert);
    if (!casesToUpdate.values().isEmpty()) {

        update casesToUpdate.values();
    }

    if (!commentsToInsert.isEmpty()) {

        insert commentsToInsert;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Davin,Thanks for ur reply,but i do get few errors ERRORs Founded :
  Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Map' at line 3 column 74
  Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '{' at line 11 column 59
  Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Not' at line 35 column 24
  Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '=' at line 36 column 35

Comment: i have changed line no 36 As Status!='closed' and blocked NOTIN.THe code got saved.The cases are not getting  identified as duplicates and not getting closed by adding the comments to the existing case.NOTE :We are using EMAIL TO CASE PREMIUM APP.How can we achieve it.....

Comment: Hi @nikkey, apologies - I typed that up yesterday without testing. I spun up a dev. org. this morning and made some adjustments to the code, and it's now working as expected. I've edited my original post with the working code.

Comment: Hi Davin ,I was waiting for ur reply.Thanks for ur help.I have tried the code in my DEVELOPER EDItion,it worked by identifying the DUPLICATES and closing it ,but didn’t add the casecomments to the existing  case(i.e previous case)

Comment: When I tried in my Org :Enterprise Edition :the code got saved ,I have created the case(case as :0001) .When  I sent an Email from Different user with same subject line (the case does not appears).Now again I have sent an email with the SAME user with same subject line (it got created as case as:0003)but did not get closed and the casecomment did not get added to the  existing case.{NOTE :WE ARE USING EMAIL TO CASE PREMIUM APP :with tat the case no :0003 got identified as  duplicate by adding an prefix(Email loop protection to the subject line)}.Request  you to kindly check and do the needful.

Comment: Comments are definitely being cloned with my code, I just checked it again.

Please be aware that Case.Subject needs to be an EXACT match for it to be detected as a duplicate as per your original design.

If you need more intelligent dup. catching, then I suggest you post some examples of Cases which should be detected as duplicates but are not.

Comment: This isn't Elance, you need to put some of the effort in too - I've asked you to investigate and provide examples of where my solution doesn't answer your original question.

Comment: @LaceySnr :This code works 90% of my requirement . when the cases are created via email, the duplicate case are been identified  and get closed auotmatically ,but the case comments are not getting added to the ORIGINAL Case which is OPEN.I tried with workflow and trigger on case comment .Not able to identify where im missing .

Comment: @nikkey I've added debug statements to my code above, could you update & rerun with debugging logging enabled and let me know the output please?

Comment: @nikkey Can you post a new question about this second part? THis is getting a bit out of hand! Try to explain exactly whave you've tried and what isn't working (and what the result should be).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16910/discussion-on-answer-by-davinc-find-duplicate-case-and-close).

Comment: I've moved most of the comments to chat so they're not lost: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16910/discussion-on-answer-by-davinc-find-duplicate-case-and-close

Comment: @Lacey : i have posted the Question as the Second part(with my requirement and which is not working) ,but u made it as a duplicate and added my previous Question.

Comment: @DavinC:In the above code can we clone the case comment first, then, close the case.